# Can't load SelectTagHelper when using the multiple attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

As a simple test I'm passing 2 lists to a javascript function, only the list without a multiple attribute populates, the second list does get the "select one or more items" option but not 1,2,3 and only after I lose focus from list2. Can anyone tell me how I can repopulate the multiselect?

```
    <select id="lstTest"></select>
    <select id="lstTest2" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

```
    function TestList(obj) {
    var x = $(obj);
    x.append('<option value="">Select one or more items</option>');
    x.append('<option value="1">1</option>');
    x.append('<option value="2">2</option>');
    x.append('<option value="3">3</option>');       
    }
```

Empty Lists

[image: Empty Lists]

List 1 after javascript call

[image: List 1 after javascript call]

List 2 after javascript call

[image: List 2 after javascript call]

Turns out the select is referencing custom js to turn it into a checkbox list as a way of selecting the items instead of highlighting. I need to treat it as a checkbox list and not just a list of options, which I'm still not sure how to do, I need to clear and add new checkboxes.

Comment: Works fine https://jsfiddle.net/1c89tw4q/ - how are you calling `TestList`?  Perhaps you could create a complete [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?  (I'm loathe to edit the code in your question for you as doing so might fix it indirectly)

Comment: Now here I thought that was a complete minimal example...It's being called by a select index change of another list,but the call is being made, the fact that it works in jsfiddle disturbs me....is it possible that jquery or another library may be affecting my call?

Comment: The code provided isn't "complete" in that there's no code that calls `TestList` - ie your other list and its change event handler - it could be that that's where the problem lies

Comment: It could be your css making it look like it's not working?

Comment: Or it could be that your `multiple` `select` has `size=1` - or maybe you have another plugin such as chosen or select2 that's changing the style / recreating the control

Comment: The event is being fired, this shows in my attached images where I have no items in the list and then 3 in the list, that is the event.

Comment: css or another plugin seems like a possibility...just not sure how to eliminate